# Crontab not working on my linux system

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I am using a simple crontab query which I want to run but seems like its not working. Here it is which I write on `sudo` user:

> 0 0 0/12 1/1 * ? * /home/homeassistant/.homeassistant/hassbianrestart.sh >
>   /dev/null 2>&1

And here in the `hassbianrestart.sh` script have this line only!

```
   #!/bin/bash
   sudo systemctl restart home-assistant@homeassistant.service
```

I also changed the file permission to 600. Then also I am not able to see it running anytime!

If I run the file directly `./hassbianrestart.sh` it works fine.

any suggestions?

Comment: I wouldn't write a `sudo` command into a crontab script. Instead use `sudo crontab -u root -e` to create a crontab job running with root permission. Also set the execution permission for your script (500). And (as pointed out in the answers) your crontab syntax is wrong.

Comment: @muclux `sudo crontab -e` should suffice, `-u root` is the default when running with `sudo`.

Comment: @Melebius ok - just to make sure ;-)

Comment: At what time or interval do you want to run the script? How did you create that cronjob?

Answer (score 3):

crontab entry takes 6 parameters "m h dom mon dow command". But you are providing 8

Comment: I generated it online, through crontab generators

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you write the cronjob wrong.
I suggest just go to [crontab guru](https://crontab.guru/) for choosing the time of cron job and then try.